# Displaying an image in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have these three models -- A "Thing" has an associated "Album", which contains typically three or four "Photo"s of the "Thing".  For the latest nine "Thing"s, I want to display the first photo of the thing from the "Album", along with other details of the thing (e.g., name, country of manufacture) using a template called "headquarters.html".

The following are my models:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Item", max_length = 60)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2)
country_of_manufacture = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Country of Manufacture", max_length = 40)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = "Creation Date", default = django.utils.timezone.now, editable = False)
album = models.OneToOneField(Album, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Album(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(verbose_name = "Photo Album", max_length = 60)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = "Creation Date", default = django.utils.timezone.now, editable = False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
photo_identity = models.ImageField(blank = True, null = True, upload_to="media/%Y/%m/%d/")
photo_in = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = "Creation Date", default = django.utils.timezone.now, editable = False)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s -- (%s)' % (self.photo_in.name + " Album", self.photo_identity)
```

This is my view.py:

```
def headquarters(request, *args, **kwargs):
last_nine = Thing.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:9]
mylist = []
for thing in last_nine:
    mylist.append (thing.album.photo_set.first().photo_identity)
return render(request, 'headquarters.html', {"nine_items" : last_nine, "URL_list" : mylist})
```

This is my template (headquarters.html):

```
{% for item in nine_items %}
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <a href="http://localhost:8000/view_a_thing/{{item.id}}/"><img class="card-img-top" src="{{ **what_do_put_in_here** }}" alt=""></a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="http://localhost:8000/view_a_thing/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a>
          </h4>
          <p class="card-text">Brand: {{item.brand}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Item ID: {{item.id}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Item price: {{item.price}}</p>
          <p class="card-text">Made in {{item.country_of_manufacture}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I cant get the first photo from "Album" to display.  Nothing comes out.  I've tried various things over three days, but with no success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Sincerely,
CKLee

Answer (score 0):

As is explained in the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields), you can use the `url` attribute of the value that is associated with the `ImageField`, so:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ item.album.photo_set.first.photo_identity.url }}" alt="">
```

Comment: Dear Willem,  Thank you so much.  You are brilliant!  Was struggling with this with sleepless nights.  With lots of appreciation, CKLee